A question on algebra isomorphism between matrix algebras
Let $A$ be an algebra over a field $F$ such that $A$ is isomorphic to the matrix algebra $M_2(F)$ as an algebra, writing $A\cong M_2(F)$. Assume that $n$ is a positive integer greater than $1$. Then, $$M_n(A)\cong M_n(M_2(F))\cong M_{2n}(F).$$ I would like to ask if this is valid. Any references to counterexamples or techniques would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much in advance for your assistance.

The statement is true but there isn't an argument here. More generally we have $M_n(M_m(F)) \cong M_{nm}(F)$. Very concretely you just do this by interpreting the LHS as block matrices.

Thank you very much, Best wishes to you.
